# "over his turned temples", from a poem by G.M.Hopkins

Tags: meaning, poetry

From Gerard Manley Hopkins' poem, "[The Furl of fresh-leaved dogrose down](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Furl_of_fresh-leaved_dogrose_down)"

> Then over his **turnèd** temples—here—
>
> Was a rose, or, failing that,
>
> Rough-Robin or five-lipped campion clear
>
> For a beauty-bow to his hat

I wonder what *turned temples* mean here. Should we read it as "his head girdled round (="turned") with a wreath (of flowers)" ? That is, does the poet use *temples* as a [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) for "head", because there's a wreath at about the temples' level?

Comment: I imagine it means a curved or curled brim of his hat, but don't know.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting song lyrics/poetry.

Comment: My question was about the "technical" meaning of a single word, not about presumed meanings behind the text in general, as usually is the case with poetry interpretations. Unless maybe in this case the meaning of "turned" is left open to interpretation from the outset..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S.

I inquired at Wiktionary's [Tea Room](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aTea_room), and [was kindly offered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aTea_room#his_turned_temples) the following explanation by Equinox:

> I suspect it means something like "sculpted" (i.e. well shaped). See
>   the sense at *[turn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn)* relating to shaping something symmetrically on a
>   lathe.

To which DCDuring added:

> There is a sense, extended from the lathe sense, in Webster 1913:
>   "Hence, to give form to; to shape; to mold; to put in proper
>   condition; to adapt.": exemplified by this, from Alexander Pope: "His
>   limbs how *turned*, how broad his shoulders spread". I would not expect
>   this to find this much used in current English, except in poetry
>   imitative of 19th century style, in further derived senses, and in
>   collocations that are almost set phrases like a "well-turned phrase"
>   and the curiously ambiguous "well-turned ankle".